# How to get the textContent length of an event

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I would like to retrieve the number of elements in an event.

I use the following function :

```
      element.bind('keyup', function (event) {
        console.log(event);
        });
```

The console.log (event) resitute me an object like this one (object shortened for the rendering)

```
n.Event {originalEvent: KeyboardEvent, type: "keyup", isDefaultPrevented: 
 ƒ, timeStamp: 13561.044999980368, jQuery2140638708200199875: true, …}
 altKey: false
 bubbles: true
 cancelable: true
 char: undefined
 charCode: 0
 ...
 scrollTop: 0
 scrollWidth: 1035
 shadowRoot: null
 slot: ""
 spellcheck: true
 style: CSSStyleDeclaration {alignContent: "", alignItems: "", alignSelf: "", 
 alignmentBaseline: "", all: "", …}
 tabIndex: 0
 tagName: "DIV"
 textContent: "abc"
 title: ""
 translate: true
 ...
```

In this object I would like to retrieve in variable the value of the length of the textContent

```
  textContent: "abc"
```

Here is a example :

https://codepen.io/gregand/pen/PoYevYQ?editors=1111

How can I recover this value ?

Comment: please share sample code snippet to replicate above scenario

Comment: @NagaSaiA I will provide an example

Comment: @NagaSaiA https://codepen.io/gregand/pen/MWgGmGK?editors=1111

Comment: in this example, childNode length is only 1 right?

Comment: @NagaSaiA   no, in the example it is a 22, look at childNodes 0: text

Comment: http://zupimages.net/viewer.php?id=19/37/b1gp.jpg

Comment: https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JjPvJoL?editors=1111 , are you looking for something like this

Comment: @NagaSaiA Thanks ! it's perfect, I did not think it was that simple

Comment: Glad it works, posted my comment as answer :)

Comment: @Greg-A what do you want to retrieve exactly? Your question starts with *the number of elements in an event*, that's easy, for the keyup event, it's one (except if we count the bubbling, then it's `event.composedPath().length`).  Then you are to talk about "the length of the childNodes", that's `1` in your screen-shot, the NodeList `childNodes` points to contains a single Node in your screenshot. Then you talk about `length: 6` that's the length of the data of that Node, ie it's textContent's length.

Comment: However, there might be a lot of different Nodes in that Element and this information is probably not what you want. So what are you trying to do exactly? And why do you want that number? Are you sure you don't prefer to have the length of the Element's textContent?

Comment: @Kaiido to get the exact length of the number of elements will allow me to use it to display the characters entered in snapshot

Comment: If you want the number of characters that have been entered, you don't need the childNodes property at all, all you need is `evt.target.textContent.length`, however, you must [edit] your question to ask this.

Comment: @Kaiido I will modify the contents of the ticket

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To achieve expected result, use below code

```
console.log(event.target.childNodes[0].length)
```

working code for reference - https://codepen.io/nagasai/pen/JjPvJoL?editors=1111

Comment: That's [the length of the TextNode's data](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#concept-node-length), i.e it's textContent string's length.. OP asked for the number of children this element has (event.target.childNodes.length)

Comment: @Kaiido, initially that is how I have created my example but as per comments and close look of the length, it is ChildNodes[0].length, 0th index is text as mentioned in question and screenshot

Comment: I added comments asking for clarifications to OP, but beware your code will fail whenever you press enter as the first character in FF, returning `undefined` (and in Chrome it will report `1`), and that's probably not what OP wants, though I admit I've got no clue what they really are after.

Comment: @Kaiido in the example if in the contenteditable I enter 6 characters, I would have wanted to recover this value in the event to be able to display it.
The only value corresponding to the numbers of characters entered is for me in event.target.childNodes [0] .length, but unlike the returned solution the one returns 1 so it can not work

Comment: Then ask for it! This answer doesn't give you the number of characters in the contenteditable div, but that's your fault for not being clear as to what you want.